# Assigning a variable after the contents are 'cut' in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am iterating through a folder of files using bash, but I need to cut the preceding path.  For instance if I have this '/temp/test/filename' I want to cut off the '/temp/test/' and store the file name to a variable so I can write a log with the filename in it.

Can anyone help me out? The problem is that the variable temp is always empty.

Here is my bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /temp/test/*
do
    if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]
    then
        continue
    fi

    temp="$file"|cut -d'/' -f3

    $file > /var/log/$temp$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log
done

exit
```

Comment: not related to question: You can use `if [[ -f "$file" ]]` and only run the commands if TRUE, so you won't have to use `continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
$ x=/temp/test/filename
$ echo ${x##*/}
filename
```

Another solution is to use `basename` :

```
$ basename /temp/test/filename
filename
```

The first solution is a [*parameter expansion*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) and it's a `bash` builtin, so we increase performance.

Your line `temp="$file"|cut -d'/' -f3` is broken.

- when you want to store the output of a command in a variable, you should do `var=$(command)`
- you need to pass the value to the `STDIN` of the command with a `here-string` (`<<<`) or with `echo value | command`

**finally**, if you'd want to use `cut` :

```
$ temp=$(cut -d/ -f4 <<< /temp/test/filename)
$ echo $temp
filename
```

Comment: Im still not seeing how I isolate the filename you seem to be isolating the pathname and throwing out the filename

Comment: As a side note, what does the <<< called/do? (google seems to ignore the search for this)

Comment: _parameter expansion_ is more fast

Comment: `<<<` is a here-string (explained in my post) See `man bash | less +/'<<<'`